# SQL query to retrieve count of Status Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a `Status` column which can have values such as

```
Completed, Failed, Started
```

I want query to retrieve the count of completed records, count of failed records and count of started records on a particular day:

```
ID    Status        Last_Updated
---------------------------------------
1     Completed     2020-02-03 15:54:59
2     Failed        2020-02-03 13:54:59
3     Started       2020-02-03 11:24:59
4     Completed     2020-02-03 15:24:59
5     Completed     2020-02-03 13:54:59
6     Started       2020-02-03 11:44:59
```

Expected output:

```
Count(status)   Status
----------------------------
3               Completed
1               Failed
2               Started
```

Comment: please show us what your current query

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple query with GROUP BY and Aggregation as below-

```
SELECT COUNT(*),Status
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Status
```

To get the results for a particular day, you can just add WHERE clause as below-

```
SELECT COUNT(*),Status
FROM your_table
WHERE CAST(Last_Updated AS DATE) = '2020-02-03'
GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `sum(1)` function as shown below.

```
create table WorkStatus (Id int, Status Varchar(20), Last_Updated datetime)
Insert into WorkStatus Values(1, 'Completed', '2020-02-03 15:54:59'),
(2, 'Failed', '2020-02-03 13:54:59'),
(3, 'Started', '2020-02-03 11:24:59'),
(4, 'Completed', '2020-02-03 15:24:59'),
(5, 'Completed', '2020-02-03 13:54:59'),
(6, 'Started', '2020-02-03 11:44:59')

Select 
     Status,
     sum(1) as TotalCount         
     from WorkStatus
group by Status order by Status
```

Here is the output.

```
Status TotalCount
-----------------   
Completed 3 
Failed    1 
Started   2
```

You can also use `Row_Number()` and `Subquery` as shown below.

```
--Using Row_Number and Subquery
Select status, max(SrNo) as TotalCount from(
Select Status, 
       Row_Number() Over(Partition By Status Order By Status) as SrNo
from WorkStatus
)a group by status
```

Here is the [db<>fiddle live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abc33fd36c4e452334b02caddb0b288c).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    Status nvarchar(100),
    Last_Updated datetime
)
INSERT INTO @table(Status,Last_Updated) VALUES
('Completed','2020-02-03 15:54:59'),
('Failed'   ,'2020-02-03 13:54:59'),
('Started'  ,'2020-02-03 11:24:59'),
('Completed','2020-02-03 15:24:59'),
('Completed','2020-02-03 13:54:59'),
('Started'  ,'2020-02-03 11:44:59');
SELECT COUNT(Last_Updated) 'Count(status)',Status  FROM @table GROUP BY Status

This is output:
Count(status)   Status
3   Completed
1   Failed
2   Started
```